# IE wont show background image as border

Tags: html, css

http://dhrumin.com/uploads/index.html

Link above is my page I have been working on. I am using border top bottom as a background image. It looks great on Chrome and FF. But on IE it will just show one solid color background image wont show up.

Can someone help me with what I am missing out?

Thanks!

Comment: `border-image` is not supported in any version of IE currently - http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image

Comment: Indeed, you will have to split your html to make a top and a bottom div with `background-image`

Comment: @Brewal, those are answers IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support the `border-image` property as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image). A workaround would be to create two divs, above and under and give them the desired `background-image` :

HTML :

```
<div class="myborder"></div>
<ul id="blockquote">
    <li>Completely formulate parallel customer service rather than B2C initiatives.</li>
    <li>Compellingly target efficient experiences whereas seamless partnerships.</li> 
    <li> Seamlessly transition customer directed applications whereas intuitive.</li> 
    <li> Holisticly mesh team building "outside the box" thinking.</li>
</ul>
<div class="myborder"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.myborder {
    width: 600px;
    height: 13px;
    background: url('quote-border.png') repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't accept this has the answer, i just moved content from 'comments'.**

border-image is not supported in any version of IE currently - [caniuse.com/#search=border-image](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image) – [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2470724/nick-r)

Indeed, you will have to split your html to make a top and a bottom div with background-image – [Brewal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2168947/brewal)

@Brewal, those are answers IMHO. – [aldux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157768/aldux)

---

From my own, i would use :before  and  :after to create what you want.

You want something better ?

```
<div class="container with THE-texture and padding">
    <div>Your content</div>
</div>
```

This way, the outter container would act like an image background-border. Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8puJf/).

it is to be IDENTICAL in visual result than what you wish. In html, you added 1 extra container. That's a difference.

Oh, let me guess, there are 'simili' borders on the sides ? -->  remove side's padding : http://jsfiddle.net/8puJf/1/

Comment: I like your trick - Good to learn but not quiet the same i was looking for!

Comment: it is to be IDENTICAL in visual result than what you wish. In html, you added 1 extra container. That's a difference